# Showing for each zero a of f, there is an open disk D(a; r) ⊂ Ω such D(a; r) contains no other zeros of f.

Tags: complex-analysis

*This seems a very well-known result in complex analysis, still I found it very hard to interpret.

Also f is analytic.

I try to attack this problem in the following way:

We can assume that **a** is a zero of f of order n, then $f(z) = (z-a)^n g(z)$.
Then g : D(a; R) → C is also an analytic function and $g(a) \not= 0.$

But here I am lost, it seems that g may have other zeros in D(a; R), and I don't see how analyticity helps us.

Comment: What about the zero function on $\Omega$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g$ is continuous. Hence,  there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|g(z)-g(a)| <\frac {|g(a)|} 2$ for $|z-a|<\delta$. This implies such that $|g(z)| \geq \frac {|g(a)|} 2$ for $|z-a| <\delta$. There is no zero of $g$ in $B(a,\delta)$.

Comment: Thanks. Clear and to the point.